# Adjetivo en una oración con el artículo definido

Tags: gramática

Vi una oración de un libro "El arte de no amargarse la vida":

"***El** final era siempre **el** esperado: casi diez minutos de aplausos ininterrumpidos por un trabajo genial.*"

Nunca he observado esa construcción - artículo con solo un adjetivo sin algún sustantivo, pero que refiere al sustantivo anterior.

De hecho, al principio pensé en que esto es superlativo. Pero en tal caso debería ser "*el más esperado*"...

En relación con esto, tengo unas preguntas:

1. ¿Cómo usar esta construcción?
2. ¿Qué tan común es ella?

La más cercana que he observado es la construcción siguiente:

"*Tyson con una pegada más demoledora que la que tiene Berbick.*"

"*Tyson con una pegada más demoledora que **la de** Berbick.*"

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es un caso de [sustantivación de un adjetivo](https://zonaele.com/sustantivacion/), y es muy común cuando se omite un sustantivo que ya ha sido mencionado. Por ejemplo:

- ¿Qué silla te gusta más? **La roja**

(en lugar de "La silla roja"), o

- Tú carga las cajas pequeñas y yo cargaré **las grandes**

(en lugar de "las cajas grandes"). El ejemplo que pones,

- El final era siempre el *(final)* esperado

es también una sustantivación. En este tipo de sustantivaciones (omisión de un sustantivo ya mencionado), tanto el artículo como el adjetivo concuerdan en género y número con el sustantivo omitido.